# Shani dev's gaze impact in improper washing legs with water

Tags: puranas, shani

From the childhood I was asked to wash my legs properly without any dry space in my legs its true if it is happened that Shani dev's gaze should be impacted on ourselves. I couldn't find any scriptures instead some old movies had this.

Comment: Truly  donot know about this subject.
But impact of grahas(as devatas) also depend on Mahadasha and sub-dashas.And in the case of Shani deva..there is the dreaded phase of 7 ½ years.Shani deva…does not cause a malefic effect…all the time.

Comment: yes, although not shani, but kali.. nala-dayamanti's suffering is based on nala not washing his feet properly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true. Shani enters thru dry/unwet space. 
Saturn signifies infections, bacteria, and virus, etc.
So when one goes out and comes back to home, brings tons of virus, bacteria to home thru their legs, hands, hair etc. And if one enters home and uses sofa, bed, etc. without a proper wash of legs, hands, etc. the microbe enters the human body, and other furniture like sofa, bed, pillows, etc, and enters every person whoever uses them, and causes diseases and misfortune to all family persons. This affects decision making capabilities and thus causes financial loses, and problems in career. This entire issue is named after the planet Shani who signifies the root cause for misfortune.

There is no need of mantra, tantra, yantra, scriptures, vedic texts, ancient evidences, etc. to understand and know this simple fact.

Comment: Unless u quote some Jyotisha texts to prove ur claims the answer remains just as ur opinion. Such answers can be deleted.. BTW if I may ask do u practice astrology?

Comment: yes, I practice. 
If there is objection, i shall write my answers only in comments. 
No problem. And i don't want any reputation marks and also I am not writing for reputation.

Comment: Ok.. no there is no objection.. u are encouraged to share ur knowledge and to write more answers.. but in this site the rule is to validate answers by quoting some authoritative sources..

Comment: Nice. I respect and obey the website rules. 
But I don't have books, proofs now. 
Although, I can not promise one source for every answer, yet, If I find any sources, then, I shall provide them in my answers. 
Most of my answers are from my experiences; and also from knowledge which I got from my Guru.

Comment: Could be the reason why we wash our legs after eating too. Nice to see your knowledge experience but for all readers to prevent debates in opinion based, its made mandatory to site references

Comment: Correct. we wash before and after eating.
Whatever knowledge I get thru practice, does not exist anywhere in internet, youtubes, text books. I don't like debates and i won't participate in any. And i don't insist people to believe my opinions.

Comment: Please delete it. I don't have any sources.

Comment: @AgamasTantras how does this apply after eating as well? I understand we need to wash after returning Home from some place outside but not after Eating. Please elaborate